# Different webpack publicPath for workers?

Tags: webpack, cdn, web-worker, webpack-4

I'm using Webpack 4, and want to serve static files via a CDN, so I've set `publicPath` to the CDN URL. But, now web workers don't work, because they cannot be loaded cross-origin. How can I set a different `publicPath` for `*.worker.js` files?

Some possibilities I've explored:

1. Using `__webpack_public_path__`, which allows `publicPath` to be set dynamically. Unfortunately, this does not work because the worker is created by a library, which I don't have access to.
2. The `publicPath` configuration option appears to allow a callback function, as well as a static path. But the callback argument does not seem to be anything useful -- it's an object which just contains a single `hash` parameter. I was hoping I could access the full file name.
3. Using the `worker-loader-cdn` webpack plugin. This does not seem to have any effect for me. This is how I've configured it, in an attempt to set the `publicPath` to a local path:

```
      ...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [utils.root('src')],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'worker-loader',
          options: { publicPath: buildConfig.assetsPublicPath },
        }],
      },
      ...
```

But the CDN path is still used. Is this usage incorrect?

Any other ideas or advice?

Comment: It appears that, for Webpack 4, the latest version of worker-loader ignores any setting of worker-loader's publicPath when output.publicPath is set in the config.

Answer (score 1):

As [of Webpack 5.77.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.77.0), there is now [an `output.workerPublicPath` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputworkerpublicpath) which I believe should do what you want. Its usage is fairly straightforward:

> Set a public path for Worker, defaults to value of output.publicPath. Only use this option if your worker scripts are located in a different path from your other scripts.

Comment: The OP would have to upgrade to Webpack 5 which does not officially support worker-loader as Webpack 5 supports Web Worker spec rather then worker-loader being an abstraction or polyfill.